# How to disable annoying messages "- Label->: xxxxxxx" in minibuffer

Tags: ergoemacs

On each action (opening new buffer, opening packages-list), I have different messages in minibuffer, how to disable it?

**UPDATE**

Looks like the problem is in ergoemacs package, beacuse when I disable it - all works normally.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've already done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem by reinstalling ergoemacs from GNU package archives **NOT FROM MELPA**.

You can read how to pin package versions [here](http://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2014/11/using-elpa-pinned-packages-gnu-emacs-24-4/).

**UPDATE**

Bug [already fixed](https://github.com/ergoemacs/ergoemacs-mode/issues/403) in **Git** version, MELPA one will soon update. To disable all messages you can also use:

```
(setq ergoemacs-messages-level 0)
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good long-term solution. Eventually, `gnu` will be updated again to whatever is currently in MELPA, and you'll need to fix the issue for real.